# form not adding to database after submitting it

Tags: php, mysql

I havet a user event form that ive created and it wont add anything to database ive checked all form elements against the database columns and read several other comments on here about this but nothing is happening can someone possibly please check this over for me many thanks in advance jan x

```
<?php
include ('config/db_connect.php');
include("config/ckh_session.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $event_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_type']);
    $event_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_date']);
    $event_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_country']);
    $event_postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_postcode']);
    $event_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_title']);
    $event_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_description']);
    $event_ltm = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_ltm']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO meets (`event_type`,`event_date`,`event_country`,`event_postcode`,`event_title`,`event_description`,`event_ltm`) VALUES ('$event_type','$event_date','$event_country','$event_postcode','$event_title','$event_description','$event_ltm')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
} else {
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

And here is the database table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meets` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`event_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`event_country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`event_postcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`event_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`event_description` text NOT NULL,
`event_ltm` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, make sure that in your form inputs, the name attribute matches with the post values that you are getting. Next, make sure that the form action is pointing to the correct php file, and that the form method is POST. Also, ensure that the form is posting the values. Your php to insert into the database is wrapped in an if->isset for the value 'submitted', so I would also ensure that that value is being passed.

Comment: ive checked the form inputs matches the  post values and all is ok on that side at the moment for testing ive got the form coming back on its self but with a success message to say New record created successfully but im not getting that success message

Comment: sorted it i had a " missing from the name submit but ty for all the comments many thanks jan x